# solving for bifurcations in nonlinear 2d system?

Tags: nonlinear-system, bifurcation

If we have this nonlinear system

$$ x ̇ = −x + 0.1y + x^2 y $$

$$ y ̇ = b − 0.1y − x^2y $$
What kind of bifurcations happen as you vary b ∈ [0,1]?

I managed to solve for equilibriums at the source and $$ x = b \space \& \space y = \frac{b}{(0.1 + b^2)} $$

aaand that's where I get a little lost. I tried making a Jacobian matrix and using that to linearize at the equilibrium points (can maybe do some trace determinant analysis) but I don't think I was able to put it together.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.